Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile builds are only supported for physical devices. attempted to build for simulator. xcode
error code : Target aot_assembly_release failed: Exception: release/profile builds are only supported for physical devices. attempted to build for simulator


Solution :
Product --> Scheme --> Edit Scheme... Run (info) Build Configuration (Debug)
enter image description here

